Who lies higher - Mother or Vedas?
Who lies higher  - Mother or God(Vedas) ?

Please clarify your question it is too terse. Who or What do you mean by 'Mother'? 'God' - is a western term...what do you mean by "God'?

Obviously God(Scriptures) will be higher as whether mother is higher authority or scriptures can only be known through scriptures.
So, obviously scriptures will have higher authority then anyone else including mother, father, guru or anyone else.

Mother..but mother's order not to be followed if against scriptures.
